# Running Rake::Pipeline.build inside of Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-pipeline

I'm trying to kick off a Rake Pipeline task from inside a Rakefile. From what I can tell the process to do that would be to do something like the [example here](http://rubydoc.info/github/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/master/Rake/Pipeline).

However, that isn't working. Here is a gist reducing that [example to barebones](https://gist.github.com/nathanhammond/6213362).

It shows a reduced test case where it works using rake-pipeline's Assetfile, but when trying to include that same exact code in a Rakefile it doesn't work.

1. Why is it failing?
2. What is a solution to make this work? (No cheating and running a system call as part of the Rakefile.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Works

It looks like one way to handle this is to execute a file, like so:

```
project = Rake::Pipeline::Project.new('Assetfile')
# project.clean      # Required for rake-pipeline 0.7.0
project.invoke
```

However, this is annoying as I have to create a file for every single rake task.

## Doesn't Work

[Looking at the code for Rake::Pipeline](https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/blob/master/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb#L89-L97) it should allow me to pass in a Pipeline, such that this code works:

```
pipeline = Rake::Pipeline.build do
  output "js"
  puts Dir.pwd
  input "js" do
    match "*.js" do
      # concatenate all JS files into a single file
      filter Rake::Pipeline::ConcatFilter, "application.js"
    end
  end
end

project = Rake::Pipeline::Project.new(pipeline)
project.invoke
```

Anybody know why this won't work? The error:

```
undefined method `manifest' for nil:NilClass
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:408:in `manifest'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:456:in `block in record_input_files'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:453:in `each'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:453:in `record_input_files'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:340:in `setup'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:326:in `block in invoke'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:321:in `invoke'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `each'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `block in invoke'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rake-pipeline-0.8.0/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:112:in `invoke'
Rakefile:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
```